# rounding integer data type

Tags: python, list

how can i round   integer 754 to 800

i tried math.ceil(754) but it wasn't working i.e the result was still the same value. i tried a round_up function but it wasnt working too. i import  math and numpy. please i will really appreaciate any guideline or advice

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about what mathematical operation you're trying to perform?

Comment: What do you want for 745?

Comment: @teapot418 Huh, I never knew that `round` accepts a negative number of digits. Brilliant suggestion, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @teapot418 thank you,  your answer worked for me, i never knew round accepts negative sign. i appreaciate

Answer (score 0):

```
number = 754
rounded_number = round(number, -2)
print(rounded_number) # Prints 800
# If number was <750 but >700 it would have printed 700
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions or if this works out for you.

Comment: notice the result of the 1st bonus solution maybe inconsistent with the others, try with `745`

Comment: @cards It returns 700 :)

Comment: No it doesn't return 700, did you try it?  If you had used `round` instead of `ceil` it might be so.

Comment: @KellyBundy thanks for the explanation.  This answer is too complex.

Comment: @MarkRansom Hi mark first of all thank you for your feedback but I have tested all of my answers and they are result correctly.

Comment: But as pointed out, there are 3 different answers and they don't all deliver the same results for every possible input.  And there's no explanation for how and why they're different.

Comment: @Cem Koçak in general truncating != rounding, `ceil`-approach != `round`. Test  _all_ your solutions with, for ex, `754` and `745` and compare you results. Then edit your answer with a proper explanation where needed